# How to extract association rules in a relational data

Tags: data-mining, rapidminer

I've downloaded a relational dataset and I want to extract frequent patterns and association rules using Rapidminer. My question is what kind of data can be mined to extract association rules and frequent patterns, relational or transactional or ...?
I try to generate frequent pattern from my relational dataset but Rapidminer error that attributes should be just binomial ???

Answer (score 0):

Look in the RapidMiner default repository for `Samples/processes/01_Learner/24_FPGrowth` where you can find a worked example that performs FPGrowth and Association Rule generation. The example shows how to transform raw data into a suitable format for these operations. The operator `Nominal to Binominal` is the one you need.

Comment: Thanks, How about attributes? for example my relational dataset has numerical attributes but in rapidminer, when I want to do FPGrowth, It errors your attribute just should be binomial. Should I ignore other kind of attributes or FPGrowth can be done just on transactional dataset?

Comment: For example attribute age have numerical values, for doing FpGrowth, should I convert it to nominal and then binominal or I ignore it ?

Comment: You can convert numerical attributes into nominals by using one of the `Discretize` operators. These divide the numerical range into named bins and then allocates each example into one of the bins. Converting straight to nominal will yield a different value for each number encountered and this is probably not what you want.